# How to put in 10 record in 1 group in excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

The simple like below the image:

[image]

Comment: Why does Mobile 1 only have 9 in the group?

Comment: What is the logic to assign a number to a given group?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it with some VBA code.

Open VBA Editor: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-help-on-using-the-visual-basic-editor-61404b99-84af-4aa3-b1ca-465bc4f45432

Add some code into sheet module:
[Double click "1" to open module code form "2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emjlh.png)

Paste this code:

```
Public Sub InsertGroups()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    
    Do While Me.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        If i Mod 11 = 1 Then
            Range("A" & i).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            Me.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = "Mobile" & i \ 11 + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Press F5, when cursor inside that Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).